# ASP.Net Core - Unexpected exception in IISHttpServer.HandleRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have `ASP.Net Core 2.2` application. This is running fine when running from Visual Studio (Both Debug & Release mode)

But when I deploy the same to IIS in any machine, it's throwing 500 error.

> "MessageTemplate": "Unexpected exception in
>   IISHttpServer.HandleRequest.",
>       "Exception": "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.GetOriginalPath()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.InitializeContext()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer.HandleRequest(IISHttpContext
>   context)",
>       "Properties": {
>           "SourceContext": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer"
>       }

On Googling, the only link:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6075

[image: Application Initilization]

Note I am running the app in IIS, with `StartMode` set to `OnDemand`.

[image: Preload Settings in IIS]

What's causing this error & how to get rid of this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this module? https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6075#issuecomment-457733980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the application loads either in IIS Express or IIS, the Swagger Document was running with no issue.

I doubted if it's really something to do with `.Net Core 2.2` & `IIS` compatibility.

So I created a sample Controller as below.

```
public class SampleController : ControllerBase //.Net Core 2.2
{
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
 {
    return Ok("APIs up & running");
 }
 }
```

Ran the above API from Visual Studio & then deployed the same on IIS with both preload = true & then false

With no surprise, API ran with no issue.

In the actual application, I was using `AWS (Cognito)` & somewhere in the recent past I had came across some article where it was mentioned AWS supports `.Net Core 2.1`

As the application is in its initial phase of development, so we tried to check the same `API` with `.Net Core 2.1`

Again as no surprise, the same set of APIs ran with no issues.

So in my case, it was `AWS Cognito` (or other services) yet don't support `.Net Core 2.2`

This is how this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the link in your question](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6075#issuecomment-489814295), you could consider **disabling** preload (as a short term measure until the underlying bug is fixed).

[image]

*i.e. change that `True` to `False`.*